# How to express simplification of an array

Tags: math-mode, arrays

How can I type the curly bracket and put the expression alongside of it? Basically, I want to simplify the array and `$\mathbf{b} = [b_1,b_2]$`

I want help to get the following output as in the picture

[image]

So, the next step would be a new array containing 3 rows instead of 4 rows where the last element of the new array would be `$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 \mathbf{b}}$`

I am using WinEdit7 and MikTex on Windows 7.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with a ton of visual formatting, but I'd prefer the second way I propose, which is, in my opinion, clear enough.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2\RE{a}} \\[3ex]
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2\IM{a}} \\[3ex]
\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 b_1} \\[3ex]
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 b_2} 
\end{matrix}
\rlap{%
  \quad
  $\displaystyle
  \left.
  \vphantom{%
    \begin{matrix}
    \dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 b_1} \\[3ex]
    \dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 b_2}   
    \end{matrix}%
  }\right\rbrace
  \dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 \mathbf{b}}
  $\quad where $\mathbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 \end{bmatrix}$%
}
\end{bmatrix}
\hphantom{%
  \displaystyle
  \left.
  \vphantom{%
    \begin{matrix}
    \dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 b_1} \\[3ex]
    \dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 b_2}
    \end{matrix}%
  }\right\rbrace
  \dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 \mathbf{b}} 
  \text{\quad where $\mathbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 \end{bmatrix}$}%
}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2\RE{a}} \\[3ex]
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2\IM{a}} \\[3ex]
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 b_1} \\[3ex]
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 b_2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2\RE{a}} \\[3ex]
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2\IM{a}} \\[3ex]
\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 \mathbf{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\text{where $\mathbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 \end{bmatrix}$}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `bigdelim` package could be of help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigdelim}

\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{array}{c}
\ldelim[{4}{*} a \rdelim]{4}{*}\\
  b\\
  c\\
  d
\end{array}
\hspace*{-0.4cm}
\begin{array}{l}
  \\
  \\
  \rdelim\}{2}{*}[$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 b} \quad \text{ where } b=...$]\\
  \\ 
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]